# Binding a button on my mouse to scroll wheel actions

Tags: mouse, scrolling

To make this perfectly clear, I do **NOT** want to bind my mouse scrolling to emulate a button. I want to push my scroll wheel to the left and have it scroll up, while pushing it to the right makes it scroll down. The reason I ask is because my mouse wheel is getting worn down and it's difficult to scroll with it.

I'm using a Logitech G500. I *could* use SetPoint, but it only provides a "Cruise Up/Down" function instead of sending actual mouse events. I need another option, one that results in generic mouse scroll events. I need a solution for both Windows and Gentoo Linux (may be two separate solutions - if one user provides a working Windows solution and another provides a working Linux solution, I will "answer" my own question pointing to both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently the version of SetPoint I was using was ancient. Updating to the latest version of "Logitech Gaming Software" (at time of writing, version 8.70.315) changed the "cruise up/down" function to "scroll up/down", and this function sends proper mouse wheel events. I've not yet been able to find a manufacturer agnostic solution to this within Windows, and I don't believe one currently exists.

Within Linux however, despite my settings for the mouse on Windows, pushing the mouse wheel left/right still sends left/right scroll events. This was swiftly remedied by running `xmodmap -e "pointer 1 2 3 0 0 4 5 8 9 10"` on log in via my desktop environment's normal autostart functionality. For those who don't speak xmodmap, up and down scroll events are actually considered to be "buttons" 4 and 5, where the buttons a human would refer to as "4 and 5" are considered by xmodmap to be buttons 8 and 9. This command disables the real scroll wheel and rebinds "buttons 6 and 7" (left/right scroll) to be 4 and 5 (up/down scroll) instead. Don't bother with "4 5 4 5" - X.Org will think you're a dirty liar for saying you have two scroll wheels and throw an error.

There's also a ZMapping config option in xorg.conf, which I haven't yet experimented with, but I probably should: some programs do not respect xmodmap and still expect scroll events from the real wheel.